# Log4j: How filter out messages from a specific class?

Tags: log4j

I want to configure my log4j logging to not log messages that are 1) coming from a specific class and 2) of a specific severity i.e. WARN.

Can someone provide sample configuration/code on how to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The information below solves the problem for standart java.util.logging package:

For filtering classes you should implement [Filter](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/logging/Filter.html) inteface and use it by calling [setFilter](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/logging/Logger.html#setFilter%28java.util.logging.Filter%29) method of Logger class:

```
public class ClassFilter implements Filter {
  public boolean isLoggable(LogRecord lr) {
    return (lr.getSourceClassName() == "SpecificClassName");
  }
}
...
Logger l = Logger.getLogger("mypackage.log");
l.setFilter(new ClassFilter());
```

For filtering severity use setLevel() method of Logger class.

Comment: Sorry, I was inattentive, this example uses standart java.util.logging package, not log4j. May be you will decide to switch to it from log4j :)